# How to pass worker options/parameters in gunicorn

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi, gunicorn, uvicorn

I am running an app which needed `uvicorn`'s asycio loop, by default it uses auto and some time it randomly assign it to `uvloop` whihc breaks the behavior. So I use the following command

```
uvicorn myapp.server.api:app --loop asyncio --port 7474
```

This forces uvicorn to use `asyncio` loop. This works as expected.

Now I am trying to move this changes to `gunicorn` and `uvicorn` as worker, but I am couldn't find a way to pass this `loop` to uvicorn.

```
gunicorn myapp.server.api:app  -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind 0.0.0.0:7474
```

But this end up using default value i.e. auto and end up selecting loop type as uvloop. How can I force it to use `asyncio` worker. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `gunicorn` does not support passing options directly to `uvicorn` workers.

So, basically, you can create a custom `UvicornWorker` class where you override the default loop policy.

Here's an example:

```py
# myapp/server/custom_worker.py

from uvicorn.workers import UvicornWorker

class CustomUvicornWorker(UvicornWorker):
    CONFIG_KWARGS = {"loop": "asyncio"}
```

Then:

```
gunicorn myapp.server.api:app -k myapp.server.custom_worker.CustomUvicornWorker --bind 0.0.0.0:7474
```

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I figured that out and did the custom class implementation that worked for me. Forgot to update the answer. Thanks again for the answer.